# Tool bar with done button on top of keyboard for Iphone using Mono Touch?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I need to add done button on tool bar with UIkeyboard(type) Number Pad, to resign the keyboard while click on done button. I used Input Accessory View but it adds to normal keyboard also ,i need to add this where i have number pad.For example i have a text field it takes only numbers there i need this.Other than places i don't want to show input Accessory view.Or else i need to show tool bar with Done button for Iphone using Mono Touch.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Could you elaborate a bit and/or add a screenshot of what you have/want ?

Comment: If your problem is that you can't see the UITextField you are typing in, a better solution is to move your View so that the UITextField is visible.  Let me know if this is what you're looking for, I have a decent example using keyboard events and animation.

Comment: I edited my question could you help me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public override UIView InputAccessoryView
    {
        get
        {
            if (dismiss == null)
            {

                UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 30));

                toolbar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;
                dismiss = new UIView(new RectangleF(-20, -120, 320, 30));
                dismissBtn = new UIButton(new RectangleF(268, 1, 50, 29));
                dismissBtn.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage("Images/done_active.png"), UIControlState.Normal);

                dismissBtn.AllEvents += delegate
                {
                    HideKeyBoard();
                };

                toolbar.AddSubview(dismissBtn);
                dismiss.AddSubview(toolbar);
                dismiss.BringSubviewToFront(dismissBtn);
                dismiss.BringSubviewToFront(toolbar);

            }
            return dismiss;
        }
    }
```