# Numeric keypad on MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a problem when using MonoTouch.Dialog to create a login screen.

If you look at the screenshots below, for a user to login they must enter their mobile number and PIN. Both of these EntryElements use a numeric keypad. The first problem is that there is no way to move from the mobile number field to the pin field. Secondly once they have entered their pin there is no 'done' button or anything to dismiss the keyboard. It's very counter-intuitive for them to scroll up in order to poke the Login button (shown in the second screenshot).

How do I get the little bar with previous, next and done buttons as shown in the third screenshot? I've seen this on some apps and was wondering if it's possible to get this working using MonoTouch.Dialog?

Keyboard in the way:
[image: Keyboard in the way]

How do you dismiss the keyboard?
[image: How do you dismiss the keyboard?]

Ideally this is what I want:
[image: Ideally this is what I want]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool bar with done button on top of keyboard for Iphone using Mono Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342011/tool-bar-with-done-button-on-top-of-keyboard-for-iphone-using-mono-touch)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. I need to do this using MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: Can you share a small repro with the source?

Comment: How you add that type of buttons? Dylan ?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to create your own DialogViewController with the following:

```
    private UIView _toolbar;
    public override UIView InputAccessoryView
    {
        get
        {
           return _toolbar;
        }
    }
```

You then create whatever you want to display in the UIView that is returned. I used a UISegmentedControl for the Next and Prev buttons and a UIBarButtonItem for the Done button.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342011/tool-bar-with-done-button-on-top-of-keyboard-for-iphone-using-mono-touch) other Stackoverflow answer shows how to add a "done" button on top of the keyboard. Using this method you can add other buttons, as well.

Comment: But how do you do this using the EntryElement in MonoTouch.Dialog?

Comment: You can accomplish that extending the DialogViewController and using the c# code for add the button to the navigation toolbar, at this point the task is the same if you were using normal UIViewControllers. So, you can add the button and link the click from done button to the dismiss keyboard.